# Android source (complete)

Tags: android, android-source

I visited some forums and downloaded source code for Bluetooth,wifi,etc API's..I was interested in viewing source code for classes like ServiceManager.java and classes in java.nio.channels, java.security packages present in android.jar ..

I had used the following command to download the source (in windows) which i currently have :

git clone git://git.source.android.com/platform/frameworks/base

Can anyone please help me out ?

Thanks,
Adithya

Answer (score 0):

Either cherry pick other packages of interest or get the whole thing with repo